# Implementing a flow "(1) if {...} else if {...} ... (2)" in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I have the following flow in C:

```
// some stuff1
//................


if (something1) {
    func1();
    func2();
} else if (something2) {
    func3();
    func4();
}

// some stuff2
```

I wonder, how can I encode that in Assembly? I mean, not exact intructions, but the flow. Should I use labels for jumping to what's inside if (something1) { ...} and "else if (something2)"? How would I return then to "// some stuff2"?

```
  ; some stuff1
  ; and then 

  cmp [some_struc], SOME_CONST
  je .... ????

  cmp [some_struc], SOME_CONST2
  je .... ????


  ; some stuff2
  ; how to better get back here?
  cmp rax, 0
```

Or should I call them as functions? Then how would I skip the 2nd "else if (something2) {" if the 1st one is true?

I can implement somehow, but I want to know how to better do that.

Comment: Using labels is the clearest approach. x86 has no conditional calls, so you'll end up using labels anyway. You can try with C *goto* before going into assembly if you like. You can also, [consult a compiler](https://godbolt.org/g/h4iUR2) to get the right inspiration :)

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it largely depends on how much code you have in these {...} blocks.
If there's limited code in them use:

```
    cmp  [some_struc], SOME_CONST
    jne  Else
    {...}
    jmp  EndIf
Else:
    cmp  [some_struc], SOME_CONST2
    jne  EndIf
    {...}
EndIf:
    cmp  rax, 0
```

If there's more code:

```
    cmp  [some_struc], SOME_CONST
    jne  Else
    call Part1
    jmp  EndIf
Else:
    cmp  [some_struc], SOME_CONST2
    jne  EndIf
    call Part2
EndIf:
    cmp  rax, 0

Part1:
    {...}
    ret
Part2:
    {...}
    ret
```

Best use `call`. I would not advice to jump to *Part1* or *Part2* and then jump back to *EndIf*.
This creates spaghetti code. Less readable and quickly becomes less maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

As i see it you have two options:

1. Use functions like you said. then all you need to do is `call func`.
   the advantage is readability and more slick code as well as automatic jump back to where you called the function, but it will cost you the overhead of using a function (setting up the registers and pushing and popping the stack pointer).
2. Use labels. this is straightforward. But you will need to declare a label for getting back to the function, or save the return address somewhere, which affects readability.

Anyway your conditional piece of code :

```
cmp [some_struc], SOME_CONST2
```

seems OK.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your first point? Precisely, how does it fit with steering the control flow, since calls are unconditional? The OP would still need to use labels. You may also want to elaborate on the fact that the second `cmp ...` needs to take into account being on the `else` branch of the first one.

Comment: of course he needs labels for the if and else part, i was talking about the function calls itself (he has a choice whether to use a function or just a label with the same code).